# Run multiple commands over SSH as sudo

Tags: linux, ssh, bash

I am trying to run commands as sudo over SSH, without success:

```
ssh -t -p 2222 name@server /usr/bin/sudo << EOF
  chmod u-r /xy 
  chmod +x /xy
  /xy
  sleep 5
  ps aux | grep xy
  sleep 5
  exit
EOF
```

This is not working. Without -t and /usr/bin/sudo:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Single line command is working:

```
ssh -p 13001 -t name@server 'sudo /xy'
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48554/sudo-over-ssh-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified might come in handy, though you already mentioned -t

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
ssh -t -p 2222 name@server "/usr/bin/sudo bash -c 'chmod u-r /xy; chmod +x /xy; ...'"
```

Comment: +1: `ssh -t name@server "sudo command here"` worked for me